# React component overriding another when set const

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a chatbot and I am having a problem when the user sends a message.

The program process is as follows: There is a json where all messages exchanged with the bot are stored and another with the bot's predefined responses. That is, when a message is sent by the user, a check is made to see if there is a reply to that message.

Initially the message appears as we can see in the following image [User message that was written in the text box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGdUL.png). The message was sent and is already in json along with the reply. It is only possible to see the user's message by placing an alert before adding the bot message graphically. When I click OK, the alert disappears and the user's message is replaced by the bot's message as shown in the following image:[Bot message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHbnG.png). When the page is refreshed, the two messages appear correctly.

So the problem is that when a message is sent by the user it appears briefly but then is being replaced but only graphically. In json it appears correctly.

Part of the code in my App.js is as follows:

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])

const AddMessage = async(text, type) => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/messages/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(text, type)
    })
    const data = await res.json()
    //console.log(data)

    alert(JSON.stringify(data))

    setMessages([...messages, data])
}


return (
    <div className='container'>
        <div className='chatbox'>
            <Header />
            <div className='div-messages'>
                <Messages messages={messages} onDelete={deleteMessage}/>
            </div>
            <SendMessage onAddMessageUser={AddMessage} onAddMessageBot={AddMessage}/>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Part of the SendMessage code:

```
const SendMessage = ({ onAddMessageUser, onAddMessageBot }) => {

    const onSubmit = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault()

    if (!text) {
        alert('Please write a message!')
        return
    }

    setMessage('')
    addUserMessage(text)
    addBotMessage(text)

}

function addUserMessage(text) {
    type = 'question'
    onAddMessageUser({ text, type })
}

function addBotMessage(text) {

    var type = 'answer'
    var flag = true

    for (let key = 0; key < botDataLength; key++) {
        if (text === botData[key].question) {
            //console.log('true');
            //console.log(botData[key].answer)
            //alert(botData[key].answer)
            text = botData[key].answer
            flag = false

        }
    }

    text = flag ? 'Sorry I don\'t understand' : text

    onAddMessageBot({text, type})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*setMessages* need the previous array :

```
setMessages(messages => [...messages, data]);
```